# Post to a Facebook page (not user page) using Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, koala

How do I post to a user page using Koala? I don't want to post to a Users' wall, but to a User page (a user can manage many pages).

The code I have right now is this:

```
facebook_graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(self.token)
facebook_graph.put_wall_post(message)
```

And I know you can do this

```
facebook_graph.put_wall_post(message, profile_id="page.id")
```

Where self.token is already in the scope of **manage_pages**, but I don't even think that is necessary.  So, how would you post to a particular page of a user which I have the access token using Koala? How do I discover the pages that a particular user has, and their correspondent ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the Koala README, this will post to a users wall:

```
@graph.put_object("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

So, the following will post to the Wall of a page (in your context):

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(self.token)
graph.put_object(page.id, "feed", :message => "I am writing on a page wall!")
```

Ensure, that the token you use is a user token (if you want to post as a user) or a page token if you want to post as the page itself.

More to read about Graph(Page): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

and Koala: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

EDIT: due to comment

To get Pages of a user

```
@graph.get_connections("me", "accounts")
```

Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: I believe I should have been more clear in my question... I am having problems on how to know the pages that the user has.

Comment: Was not clear for me. See my update above. `graph.get_object("me", "accounts")`

Comment: `#get_object()` is a generic method to access the FacebookGraphApi.
Method is shown here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala within the MainPage.

Comment: @deradon undefined method for me too.

Comment: `@graph.get_connections('me','accounts')`